# C# Click on image opens YouTube Video

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  have an ImageButton as such:

```
    <asp:ImageButton  runat="server" width="640" height="360" ID="imgButton" OnClick="ImageClick" />
```

When I click on it I do some validation. If everything check out OK, what I like to do is to replace that image with a 
Youtube video as such:

```
   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ZtcptQruWDg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Wondering what the best way to do this would be.

Comment: Are you talking about client-side, or server-side?  Take into account that depending on "level" of validation you're doing, you should always do validation for database information on the server side, as client-side can be overridden by people who know what they're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pure javascript/jQuery solution:

**Html that is rendered from an ImageButton**

```
<input type="image" src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-107x160-DesiccationCracks.jpg" title="Click to disable this rule" id="imgButton" name="imgButton">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){

    $('#imgButton').click(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith(' <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ZtcptQruWDg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    })

});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rL4u0gys/)

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have , it seems you are interested in server side code, and i would suggest to but that button into a ASP Panel and on button click use following code, assuming panel id is "P"

```
 p.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<iframe width='560'  height='315' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/ZtcptQruWDg' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
```